# Angular pass a Component as ng-template of another Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, ng-template

In my Angular 6 app I need to pass a Component to another Component as its [ng-template](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template).

The reason is that I have a **Component A** that I need to replicate many times, but each time it has to include different components (let's call them **Component B** and **Component C**) which **have the same Inputs**.

**Component A** template:

```
<div class="row-detail-panel">
  <h4 class="row-detail-panel-title">{{ newEntity ? 'Add new' : 'Edit this'}} {{ entityName }}</h4>

  <!--THIS IS THE COMPONENT I WANT TO INJECT-->
  <app-component-b
    [inline]="true"
    [form]="form"
  ></app-component-b>
  <!--END-->

  <!--some more html code here-->
</div>
```

And I create a **Component A** instance using:

```
<app-component-a
  [entity]="row"
  [entityName]="entityName"
></app-component-a>
```

---

So I thought about using `ng-template`, so changing the **Component A** template as follows:

```
<div class="row-detail-panel">
  <h4 class="row-detail-panel-title">{{ newEntity ? 'Add new' : 'Edit this'}} {{ entityName }}</h4>

  <ng-template></ng-template>

  <!--some more html code here-->
</div>
```

And creating a **Component A** instance using:

```
<app-component-a
  [entity]="row"
  [entityName]="entityName"
>
  <app-component-b
    [inline]="true"
    [form]="form" <!--PROBLEM: "form" does not exist here-->
  ></app-component-b>
</app-component-a>
```

So I can easily inject **Component C** instead of **Component B** as **Component A**'s ng-template:

```
<app-component-a
  [entity]="row"
  [entityName]="entityName"
>
  <app-component-c
    [inline]="true"
    [form]="form" <!--PROBLEM: "form" does not exist here-->
  ></app-component-c>
</app-component-a>
```

**PROBLEM**:

the variable `form` that I need to inject to **Component B** or **Component C** exists only inside **Component A** and **not** in **Component A's parent** (for some reasons I cannot move it one level up).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you consider using dumb component? I think it may be easier that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried by simply doing:

```
<app-component-a #compA
  [entity]="row"
  [entityName]="entityName">
  <app-component-b
    [inline]="true"
    [form]="compA.form"
  ></app-component-b>
</app-component-a>

// component-a.html

<div class="row-detail-panel">
  <h4 class="row-detail-panel-title">{{ newEntity ? 'Add new' : 'Edit this'}} {{ entityName }}</h4>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

In order for this to work, the `form` member defined in the A component should be public, and preferably `readonly`.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is this:

When you call component A, you pass an ng-template to that as follows:

```
<app-component-a> 
   <ng-template *ngIf=”condition; else elseBlock”> 
      <app-component-b></app-component-b> 
   </ng-template> 
   <ng-template #elseBlock> 
      <app-component-c></app-component-c> 
   </ng-template>
</app-component-a>
```

Now in your app-component-a.ts you do this:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef;
```

So basically template will get component b or c based on your condition.

And then in component A template, you do this:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
```

So now your ng-container will get Component B or C based on your condition.

As far as your form is concerned, i'm afraid the only thing I can think of is to create a service and provide it in component A, inject it in A,B and C and share the form in that service.

But if you include component B and C the way I have shown above, Angular will handle creation and destruction of your B and C components on it's own.

Otherwise when your ng-template condition changes, your component B will not be destroyed when component C is instantiated.

**Edit:**

One more thing I can think of is that if you are not calling component B or C as soon as A is instantiated, you could also emit (@Output) form from A to A's parent oninit of A. This way when B or C is called, A's parent will have access to form and it can pass it to B or C.

Comment: this does not solve the issue that OP described in relation to the inputs, you just gave a suggestion